# How to solve a conditional inequality?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I am trying to use *Mathematica* to solve a conditional inequality.

> Find all (real) numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $|a| + |b| \ge
>  2/ \sqrt{3}$ and for any real $x$ the inequality $ |a\sin x + b \sin 2x|
>   \le 1 $ holds

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294971/find-big-a-b-big-biga-big-bigb-big-ge-2-sqrt3-text-and-f) for more info.

I tried the expression

```
Reduce[{ForAll[{x}, Abs[a*Sin[x] + b*Sin[2 x]] <= 1] && 
  Abs[a] + Abs[b] >= 2/Sqrt[3]}, {a, b}, Reals]
```

Unfortunately, the above expression is running for a few hours without any output. Is there a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: could you please improve the title?

Comment: @ chris: What do you suggest?

Comment: something slightly less generic!

Comment: @ chris: Hope this is it now.

Comment: I think this title covers most questions asked on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps

```
sol = Reduce[ForAll[{u}, -1 <= u <= 1 \[Implies] 
   Abs[a*u + b*2 u Sqrt[1 - u^2]] <= 1 && 
    Abs[a*u - b*2 u Sqrt[1 - u^2]] <= 1 && 
    Abs[a] + Abs[b] >= 2/Sqrt[3]], {a, b}, Reals]
(*
  (a == -(4/(3 Sqrt[3])) && (b == -(2/(3 Sqrt[3])) || b == 2/(3 Sqrt[3]))) ||
   (a ==  4/(3 Sqrt[3])  && (b == -(2/(3 Sqrt[3])) || b == 2/(3 Sqrt[3])))
*)
```

Polynomial systems are usually easier and `Sqrt` can be often be converted.  If the degree is not too high, you can get a result.  Here we can replace `Sin[x] -> u` and `Sin[2x] == 2 Sin[x] Cos[x] -> 2 u * (± Sqrt[1 - u^2])`, where `±` is to be interpreted such that both resulting inequalities must be satisfied.  This is because all combinations of signs of sine and cosine are possible if `x` ranges over all real numbers.

*[The simplicity of the answer suggests that perhaps a simple mathematical solution might exist, but I have to go.  Someone else?]*

Comment: @ Michael E2 : Thank you for your attention to the problem. I need some time to think about that. However, I have doubts concerning the answer.  I think it should be XOR instead of &&  (see [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_connective) )  in Abs[a*u + b*u Sqrt[1 - u^2]] <= 1 &&    Abs[a*u - b*u Sqrt[1 - u^2]] <= 1. Also as a rule, the solution of an inequality is of the inequality form too.

Comment: It appears, that the inequalities within `Reduce` have `b*u` instead of `2*b*u`. It also may well be, that the task is interesting precisely because of the possible solutions being restricted to a finite number of points.

Comment: @ Michael E2: I got  &&. Sorry, your code is running for a few hours without any output. I think the upvoter  somewhat hurried.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP The 2's were left off accidentally.  The output is correct.

Comment: @MichaelE2 @user64494 On my machine (MMA 10.1, win7x64 enterprise) the code with and without correcting the coefficient before `b` run quite quickly (few seconds max) and with the correct coefficient gave the cited result.

Comment: @user64494 Do you mean we should expect the answer to `z <= 1 && z >= 1` should be, as a rule, an inequality?

Comment: @ Michael E2: Up to your answer, a==1 && b== 1 is a solution. But the output of Plot[Abs[Sin[x] + Sin[2 x]], {x, 0, 10}] contradicts it.

Comment: @ Michael E2: I think if one takes And instead of Or in your answer, then the right and unexpected answer which consists of 4 solutions is obtained. You were right in that place. Can you kindly edit your answer to accept it?

Comment: @user64494 You're welcome.  Sorry for the slow response, and perhaps lack of clear thought & explanation -- I'm at a conference and my time is limited.